# Run/Debug Configuration Highlights Selected Main Class in Red for Plain Application

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can't seem to get my debug configuration to accept the main class i have chosen.

According to the IDE everything seems to be ok and running correctly. This is from the Hello World template that comes out the box.

[image]

But i have another application where my specified main class is in Blue.

[image]

I was wondering if anybody knows what the issue is? Or even if it is an issue?

Cheers all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij doesn't seem to like the default package being the source of the main class. So i created a package and referenced from it.

[image]

[image]